# context:component-scan takes more than 2 minutes to complete

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to springs. I tried using context:component-scan to scan my package like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
```

However it seems very time consuming and takes more than 2 minutes. Is there a way to improve its performance

Comment: Without more info it'll be difficult to diagnose anything useful. How big is your actual package/classpath that's being scanned?

Comment: I have around 5 classes in the mentioned package.

I am creating beans for around 200 classes using @Autowired in the above classes.

Comment: How do you know that `base-package` scan is taking more time but not complete initialization?

Comment: @Jatin: Is there any specific way to check seperately the time taken for scan and time taken for initialization

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of classes it's normal to take that long. Most likely you also scan some classes that should not be scanned. You can optimise it by scan only the packages you need. for example if you have annotated controlers you can scan only the package witch contains them.  `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.web.controller">`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `<context:include-filter />` and `<context:exclude-filter />` elements within the `<context:component-scan />` element to further limit the scope of the scan.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building an app using Spring MVC?

**Mostly developers make the mistake of loading the beans twice by scanning the same thing in application-context and *-dispatcher-servlet.xml.**

Am thinking out load, in your web.xml you must have loaded a context using contextloaderlistener and declared a SpringDispatcher servlet.

Just make sure that you only load the controllers beans inside *-servlet.xml file.

Your server layer(service and dao classes) should be loaded from the files you load via contextloaderlistener.

Like Jukka mentioned, you can avoid this by using exclude filter on @Controller annotation in the application-context.xml